# How to fit all the elements within the window height?

Tags: html, css, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to fit all the elements of my page only in the window size that I'm given. How can I make it so the game div stay as far bottom as possible, but covers as much of the title as it's needed for it to remain on the page without the need to scroll?

I've tried setting the position to absolute, but that makes it so that it instantly moves to the top and covers everything, instead of just covering the minimum amount possible.

[image: Page screenshot]

Below is the relevant code:

HTML

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Roll A Zombie!</title>
        <script src="Game/Build/UnityLoader.js"></script>
        <script>
                var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "Game/Build/Game.json");
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="Assets/banner.png" alt="Game Title" id="gameBanner">
        <img src="Assets/left.png" alt="Left Zombies" id="leftZombie">
        <img src="Assets/right.png" alt="Right Zombies" id="rightZombie">

        <div id="game">
            <div id="gameContainer"/>
        </div>
    </body>
```

And the CSS

```
    body{
        background-color: #c574ac;
        background-image: url("Assets/background.png");
        background-position: center;
    }

#gameBanner{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#game{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto; 

    border: 5px solid #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 
                0px 20px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); 
}

#leftZombie, #rightZombie{
    top:30%;
    z-index: -1;
}

#leftZombie{
    float:left;
    position:absolute; 
    left: 0;
}

#rightZombie{
    float:right;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered putting the game div inside a wrapper with `position:relative;height:100%;min-height:height_of_game` then using `position:absolute;bottom:0` on the game div? If that doesn't work, please share your markup/CSS to reproduce the situation you're facing, so we can understand how you're approaching this.

Comment: @Serlite I've updated the post with the code, however keep in mind that the Unity Player is generated after the site has completely loaded, so trying to replicate it might be difficult.